# Capturing comma separated list as list through regex in scala

Tags: regex, scala

I have input in the following format:

```
"DataType: FieldName1, Fieldname2,FieldName3"
```

Where you can have 1 or more field names.

So for example:

```
User: Name, Address
Person: Age, Address,DOB
```

I'm trying to capture the DataType in a string and the fields in an array using scala group capture, this is what I have till now:

```
val dataTypeAndFieldsRegex = """(.+):(.*(,.*)?)""".r

"Person: Age, Address, DOB" match {
  case dataTypeAndFieldsRegex(dataType, fields, _*) => {
    println("dataType: " + dataType)
    println("fields: " + fields)
  }
```

The problem is that fields here is a string.
How can I capture the fields as an array?

Comment: I don't think you can split a capture group into an array.. because that's what it is, one group. The commas are part of your pattern. Not with pattern-matching anyway.

Comment: I totally agree with @m-z

Comment: Regex are probably not the right tool for the job if you really want to have an array and not split the string afterward. I advice you to have a look into [Parboiled](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled) as that is a much more flexible way of parsing stuff. It maybe be a bit scary at first look but I'm quite sure that you can write your parser in a couple of lines.

Comment: Or scala's built-in parser combinators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With scala's parser combinators you can have these kind of nice little rules, and combine them in order to parse more complex data:

```
object SO29900085 extends App {
  case class Schema(dataType: String, fields: Seq[String])

  object SchemaParser extends RegexParsers {
    def dataType: Parser[String] = """[^:]*""".r ^^ { _.toString }
    def field: Parser[String] = """[a-zA-Z]+""".r
    def fields: Parser[List[String]] = (field ~ ",".?).* ^^ { _.map(_._1) }

    def schema: Parser[Schema] = (dataType ~ ":" ~ fields) ^^ {
      case dataType ~ ":" ~ fields => Schema(dataType, fields)
    }
  }

  println(SchemaParser.parse(SchemaParser.schema, "User: Name, Address"))
  println(SchemaParser.parse(SchemaParser.schema, "Person: Age, Address,DOB"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll just need to split `fields` using the following command :

```
 fields.split(",")
```

I don't know how you intend to use that since if you try to print it, the output will look mostly like this :

```
dataType: Person
fields: [Ljava.lang.String;@29e495ff
```

Comment: Yes, that is true. But I'm trying to find out how to capture the comma separated list as an array through group capture (without having to 'split' the string)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what do you mean with `group capture`

Comment: Through the regex... 
Something like (imaginative code here):
 `case dataTypeAndFieldsRegex(dataType, fields: List[String], _*) => {
    println("dataType: " + dataType)
    fields.foreach(println)
  }`